# finding object from array of objects in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

```js
const Schema = new Schema({
    queueId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: {
            unique: true
        }
    },
    players: {
        type: [
            {
                ID: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                    index: {
                        unique: true
                    },
                    default: 'null'
                },
                name: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                    default: 'null',
                },
                queueId: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                    default: 'null'
                }
            }
        ],
        required: true,
        default: []
    },
    isAvailable: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true
    },
    isFull: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    }
});
```

How do I use `findOne()` to get the object from `players` which is an array

Im currently trying this code but it returns `null`

```js
const doc = await List.findOne({ players: { ID: 'id' } });
```

basically `players` is an array and I want to find ID from the players array of objects and get the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  "players.ID": "1"
},
{
  "players.$": 1
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PFdFl4vMSty)

---

```
db.collection.find({
  "players.ID": "1"
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MximVZ5T1s-)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "players.ID": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$players"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "players.ID": "1"
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_EEAZAdBK3_)

Comment: Any way to get this using `findOne()`?

Comment: @Firez should work just like the second part of answer

Comment: @cmgchess second part gives an array, I am trying to get an object. I know using [0] (limit will be 1) will give me an object but I would still like to know if I could this in object form.

Comment: @Firez My third answer use aggregate `$unwind`